# MySQL cursor declaration with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor, syntax-error

I am attempting to declare a cursor with multiple joins in a stored procedure. The query runs perfectly outside of the stored procedure, but the stored procedure gives me an error at the cursor declaration, claiming there is a syntax error.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getCheaters;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE getCheaters()
BEGIN

DECLARE id INT (11);
DECLARE first_name  VARCHAR (255);
DECLARE last_name VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE file_name VARCHAR(255);

DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;
DECLARE loop_cntr INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE userCursor FOR
    SELECT last_name, first_name, users.id
    FROM users JOIN documents ON (users.id = documents.user_id)
    JOIN licenses ON (licenses.user_id = users.id)
    WHERE multi_user_license_id IS NULL
    GROUP BY last_name, first_name
    HAVING count(documents.title) > 60;


DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    SET no_more_rows = TRUE;

OPEN userCursor;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO num_rows;

read_loop: LOOP
    /*Do stuff*/
    IF no_more_rows THEN
        CLOSE userCursor;
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    SET loop_cntr = loop_cntr + 1;
END LOOP;

END $$
DELIMITER;
```

And I get ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOR
        (SELECT last_name, first_name, users.id
        FROM users JOIN docu' at line 13

Does any one see where my error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```sql
...
DECLARE userCursor FOR
...
```

by:

```sql
...
DECLARE userCursor CURSOR FOR
...
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/531162/1)</kbd>